# Sharepoint Online - Adding HasAttachments to the property restrictions of Advanced Search

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to add HasAttachments to the property restrictions of advanced search in sharepoint online, but I can't get it to return any results, I believe this means I am not setting it up correctly but I haven't been able to find any guidance via googling.

I've managed to add other extra properties without issue that have returned expected results. The below code shows the extra property for "Email To" as well as my attempt to add "HasAttachments" .

```
<PropertyDef Name="EMAILTO1" DataType="text" DisplayName="Email To"/>
<PropertyDef Name="EmailSendDate" DataType="datetime" DisplayName="Email Sent Date"/>
<PropertyDef Name="HasAttachments" DataType="boolean" DisplayName="Attachments"/>
```

And here are the entries for it under ResultTypes

```
    <ResultTypes>
        <ResultType DisplayName="All Results" Name="default">
            <KeywordQuery/>
            <PropertyRef Name="Author" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Description" />
            <PropertyRef Name="FileName" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Size" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Path" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Write" />
            <PropertyRef Name="CreatedBy" />
            <PropertyRef Name="ModifiedBy" />
            <PropertyRef Name="EMAILFROM1" />
            <PropertyRef Name="EMAILTO1" />
            <PropertyRef Name="EmailSendDate" />
            <PropertyRef Name="HasAttachments" />
        </ResultType>
        <ResultType DisplayName="Documents" Name="documents">
            <KeywordQuery>IsDocument="True"</KeywordQuery>
            <PropertyRef Name="Author" />
            <PropertyRef Name="DocComments"/>
            <PropertyRef Name="Description" />
            <PropertyRef Name="DocKeywords"/>
            <PropertyRef Name="FileName" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Size" />
            <PropertyRef Name="DocSubject"/>
            <PropertyRef Name="Path" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Write" />
            <PropertyRef Name="CreatedBy" />
            <PropertyRef Name="ModifiedBy" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Title"/>
            <PropertyRef Name="EMAILFROM1" />
            <PropertyRef Name="EMAILTO1" />
            <PropertyRef Name="EmailSendDate" />
            <PropertyRef Name="HasAttachments" />
        </ResultType>
```

The property looks like below on the webpart.

[How this looks on the Advanced Search Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn2E1.png)

I assume I am a) either choosing the incorrect datatype b) not entering enough information in the webpart when doing the search I have tried leaving it blank or trying a variation of true, True, TRUE etc. c) You cant search by this.